# Why Laravel doesn't have a DI Container?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I am starting working with Laravel, and I see it handles DI. But in contrast to other frameworks, there is not a IoC container. So, how does Laravel know how to inject the dependencies?

Answer (score 9):

There is an IoC in Laravel framework.

> The Laravel service container is a powerful tool for managing class dependencies and performing dependency injection.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container